# How do you add two-way binding to a non-input element like <select> in angular 2+

Tags: angular

I want to add two-way data-binding to the select drop-down list. but as the dropDown array is not an object. It is not working properly. How do I set two-way data binding on the drop-down list.

In this code data that will be displayed in the dropdown list is coming from a service in the form of an array. Over which ng for loops and shows the output. But I want to add two-way data binding to the drop-down list in the `<select>` tag. As the data is in the form of array I cant use it in two way binding. How to do it

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="sel1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Choose Course</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
          <option *ngFor="let data of dropDownArr"  [(ngModel)]="data.course" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" ngDefaultControl>{{data.course}}</option>          
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>





//APP COMPONENT TS
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DropDownService } from './drop-down.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [DropDownService]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  dropDownArr = [];
  onSubmit(event: Event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  constructor(public dropdown: DropDownService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
       this.dropDownArr = this.dropdown.getData();
  }
}






// SERVICE TS
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class DropDownService {
  courses: { course: string }[] = [
    { course: 'Mobile Development' },
    { course: 'Web Development' },
    { course: 'IOS Development' },
    { course: 'Android Development' }
  ];

  getData() {
    return this.courses;
  }
  setData(obj: { course: string }) {
    this.courses.unshift(obj);
  }
  constructor() { }

}
```

Comment: what angular/angularjs version are you using?

Comment: I am using angular 2

Answer (score 3):

Add `[(ngModel)]` to the `select` itself and remove it from the `option`. There is no sense to add `ngModel` to `option`. Instead you need to set the `[value]` property of your option.

```
<select class="form-control" id="sel1" [(ngModel)]="selectedItem">
    <option *ngFor="let data of dropDownArr"  [value]="data.course" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" ngDefaultControl>{{data.course}}</option>          
</select>
```

Component

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  dropDownArr = [];
  selectedItem;

  onSubmit(event: Event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  constructor(public dropdown: DropDownService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
       this.dropDownArr = this.dropdown.getData();
  }
}
```

Comment: when you add it to select. It gives error of "cannot read course on undefined"

Comment: selected item doesnt take values from data.course So can we say its two way bound

Comment: what I understand from two-way binding is if you change the value in view it should change the model and if model is changed view should update.  I cant seem to get my head around here as to how two-way binding is working here.

Comment: how do you change the ngmodel from component here. can you please give the example in code

Comment: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html. Lets clear comments to clear

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the `[(ngModel)]` on the select not on the options. It will then take the value of the selected option.

However it doesn't make sense what you are currently trying to do. You want ngModel to map to a separate value (lets call it selectedCourse) to represent the selected item. Then youd have something like:

```
<select class="form-control" id="sel1"  [(ngModel)]="selectedCourse"
                [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" ngDefaultControl>
  <option *ngFor="let data of dropDownArr" [value]="data.course">{{data.course}}</option>          
</select>
```

Comment: but how do you pass it the value. when the data is in array format

Comment: I dont think it makes sense to have the [(ngModel)] set to data.course. It should be set to a single value call it selectedCourse for example and have that on the select. Ill update my answer in a sec

Comment: I dont want it to map to seperate value. It wouldnt be two way binding if we choose to bind it to seperate value

Comment: It is a two way binding. When selectedCourse changes the select element will swap to the correct option. Conversely selecting an option will set the selectedCourse. What you were trying to do doesn't make sense as it was sort of trying to bind the value of itself to itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the initial value to `select` and populate the `options` like this,

```
<select class="form-control" id="sel1" [(ngModel)]="dropDownArr[0].course">
 <option *ngFor="let data of dropDownArr" [value]="data.course" ngDefaultControl>{{data.course}}</option>          
</select>
```

**EDIT**

Since you mentioned it is a template driven form, you also need to add a `name` attribute to `select` tag

```
<select class="form-control" name="sel1" id="sel1" ngModel>
 <option value="" disabled>Choose a state</option>
 <option *ngFor="let data of dropDownArr" [value]="data.course" ngDefaultControl>{{data.course}}</option>          
</select>
```

See [this](https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor#how-to-use-select-controls-with-form-directives) for more info

Comment: it will bind to only one of the values. I want the whole select to be two way bound

Comment: is your form template driven or reactive?

Comment: template driven but it should be independent of that

Comment: Updated my answer. See Edit section. If you don't have an initial value but want to bind your options, simply having `ngModel` and a valid `name` attributes are enough (along with first `option` tag having an empty `value`)